# Is incluing many .js files via one php file a good practice?

Tags: php, javascript, include

I'm working on a big project, for organization purpuses it links to many .js files, some for jQuery plugins some for the base javascript code. Every link to a .js file in index.php generates a new request to the server. Is it a good practice to have only one link to a PHP file that fopens all the .js files and echoes the content?

Will explain better with an example, this:

```
<script src="/js/scripts.php"></script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script src="/js/1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/2.js"></script>
...
<script src="/js/n.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the development you should separate the file cause the sake of debugging and organizing. But in production, files should be minified to one and pushed to CDN :)

Comment: Perfect, I have no knowledge on this, can you point me out some resources in order to minify and pushing JS to CDN? (php libraries, apache config, etc). Thanks!

Comment: this depends on the framework you use. And there are many ways to archive this, but you can begin with finding what do you have with your php framework.